# Meteor Iron Router splash message edit

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I would like to change the splash message of Iron Router failure .Instead of "Organize Your Meteor Application" ,add something user friendly.How to start with this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard coded [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/b37edb76073ee2f5a8df4cb3004cec92128cf4ed/lib/templates.html) in iron:router repo.
You can fork it and change this line to yours.

But why do you need this? Line 54 [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/9c369499c98af9fd12ef9e68338dee3b1b1276aa/lib/router_client.js) can give you the idea of how `iron:router` uses your templates.

```
Router.prototype.lookupNotFoundTemplate = function () {
  if (this.options.notFoundTemplate)
    return this.options.notFoundTemplate;

  return (this.routes.length === 0) ? NO_ROUTES_TEMPLATE : DEFAULT_NOT_FOUND_TEMPLATE;
};
```

Only if you don't have any routes defined and no config for `notFoundTemplate`, you will see such message, define it via router config.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    notFoundTemplate: 'pageNotFound'
});
```

Comment: I want to give better UI when users are trying to access an app(developed on meteor) from a device / browser that does not support meteor

Comment: @SaiRam if browser does not support meteor, then, probably it is not a browser :)

Comment: But there are some versions of browser that don't support meteor right??

Comment: @SaiRam well, not really.